# Delete keywords from filenames in python

Tags: python, filenames

I am fairly new to programming and wanted to delete a certain keyword like 'website.com' from all the filenames in a folder by looping through and searching for the keyword.Please help......thanx in advance!

This is some code I have written so far to loop through the files.

```
import os
rootdir = r'C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\testfiles'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Update:

Thanx to kponz.....my updated code is
    import os
    rootdir = r'C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\myfiles'
    str = " text"
    for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
      if str in filename:
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace(str, ""))
      else:
        continue

But now I am getting the following error
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace(str, ""))
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:     'even more text.txt' -> 'even more.txt'

I am trying to delete the word 'text' from file named:

```
even more text.txt
some text.txt
much more text.txt
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?  When you set the pathname, put a lower-case r in front of the path string like this: path = r"C:\etc."  The error you are getting is probably because \t in \testfiles means something else to python.

Comment: Thanks....that solved the pathname problem for the program but I still could not figure out the code for renaming the files by removing certain keywords...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace a specific keyword, you can just use the string replace function:

```
import os
rootdir = r'C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\testfiles'
str = "example.com"
for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
    if str in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(rootdir, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(rootdir, filename.replace(str, ""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

Comment: Tried it....its not working when trying to print out the string..printing the same stuff out

Comment: In that case, you would need to do str = str.replace("website.com", ""), or print(str.replace("website.com", ""))

Comment: yup working fine now thanx.....could you also help me integrating it to a renaming function!! I am not that much familiar with renaming stuff.

Comment: getting this error - os.rename(filename, filename.replace(str, "")) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'even more text.txt' -> 'even more .txt'...........................I was trying to delete the word 'text' from a file named 'even more text.txt' bt i am getting this error.Please help

Comment: That problem would appear if you aren't running the python script from the same directory - I've updated the example to fix that issue

Comment: Thanx man!!!!! Solved my whole problem......thanx a lot!!! It was my first experience on stackoverflow and it went great cause of you.....thanx kponz!!!!

Comment: btw I am sorry....I don't have that much reputation to give your answer a upvote bt as soon as I make enough repo...I will surely give it a upvote!!